# How to calculate values from another mysql table?

Tags: mysql

I have two mysql table

payment table looks like

```
id invoiceID   type  amount  date
1  0001        cash  1.00  2018-10-16
2  0001        cash  2.00  2018-10-16
3  0001        cash  1.00  2018-10-17
4  0001        cash  1.00  2018-10-17
5  0002        cash  5.00  2018-10-17
```

money table

```
id  type  amount  date
1   CASH 10.00  2018-10-16
2   CARD 20.00  2018-10-16
3   CASH 18.00  2018-10-17
4   CARD 90.00  2018-10-17
```

By using InvoiceID in payment table

1. sum up all cash amount belongs to the invoiceID(with date).
   for eg 3 is the sum amount of cash belongs to 2018-10-16 
   and 2 is the sum amount of cash belongs to 208-10-17 based on the above table example.

2.Subtract 3(sum amount) from amount in money table where type cash and date 2018-10-16 (will get cash 7 in money table where 2018-10-16)

3.subtract 2(sum amount) from amount in money table where type cash and date 2018-10-17.(will get cash 16 in money table where 2018-10-17)

Expected ouput should be

money table

```
id  type  amount  date
1   CASH 7.00  2018-10-16
2   CARD 20.00  2018-10-16
3   CASH 16.00  2018-10-17
4   CARD 90.00  2018-10-17
```

I have only invoiceID. First require to find which all are the date added belongs to the specific invoiceID(0001) for example 2018-10-16 and 2018-10-17 for the cash from the payement table

Comment: What is expected output as per your sample data ?

Comment: 2 and 3rd point is my expected output.

Comment: Please expected output in tabular format - Words are difficult to visualize

Comment: subtract value from the money table

Comment: and i have only invoiceID.First require to find which all are the date added belongs to the specific invoiceID(0001) for example 2018-10-16 and 2018-10-17 (only for type CASH )from the payement table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Firstly, in a [Derived table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), determine the **total amount** for the  `invoiceID = '0001'`, for every combination of `type` and `date`. To do that, we use `Group By` on `type` and `date`, and determine total amount using [`SUM()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) function.
- Now, do a `Left Join` from `money` table to previously determined Derived Table, on `date` and `type`.
- Subtract total amount from the amount of money table. In case of no matching row in the derived table, use [`Coalesce()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function to consider 0.

Try the following (it seems [you want to Update the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52860513/how-to-calculate-values-from-another-mysql-table/52860698?noredirect=1#comment92638049_52860698) instead):

```
UPDATE
  money AS m
LEFT JOIN 
  (
   SELECT 
     type, 
     SUM(amount) AS total_amount, 
     date 
   FROM payment 
   WHERE invoiceID = '0001'
   GROUP BY type, date
  ) AS dt 
  ON dt.type = m.type AND 
     dt.date = m.date 
SET m.amount = m.amount - COALESCE(dt.total_amount, 0)
```

Comment: is it possible to find all date belongs to invoiceID..for example 0001 have two dates 2018-10-16 and 2018-10-17?

Comment: @Diamond this query is finding for all the dates only. I have not put any restriction on the date. Just used where condition on invoiceId only

Comment: subtracted values are not updating to the money table amount.In money table amount should be updated with new subtracted value.this is expected output know

Comment: @Diamond ok. From your problem statement it seemed that you wanted to Select the revised money table value. Check the updated answer now.